# Texts about Dwork's work

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, p-adic

I want to ask about references to papers, that probably exist, which explain the articles of Bernard Dwork starting from "The rationality of the zeta function of an algebraic variety" to "On the Boyarsky principle".

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. You want papers that refer to Dwork's work? That expound upon Dwork's work? What does "probable existing" mean here?

Comment: in reality,for the present moment I am studying a number of Dwork papers and I find several difficulties to  to assimilate them, except the one about the rationality of the zeta function (1960) thanks to the explication of neal Koblitz, and in order to understand the oters  I hope that exist papers which explicate them like that of Neal Koblitz

Comment: Have you tried googling "the work of Bernard Dwork ?" .  Google is a really good tool for questions like yours.

Comment: yes aginensky, but I didn't succeed to have an easy explanation, I tried many times to read his papers(those since 1962 to 1980), but I could'nt understand them

Comment: Certainly check out Koblitz's book (if you haven't already) entitled, "p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions" as mentioned [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/241876/)...

Comment: Thank you very much Benjamin Dickman, but as I had mentionned above my problems reside on the Dwork 's papers from 1962 to 1983, but I will very happy if I can receive a copy of your thesis aboout the dwork's proof of the rationality of the zeta function

Answer (score 8):

MR0498577 (58 #16672) Reviewed 
Katz, Nicholas
Travaux de Dwork. (French. English summary) Séminaire Bourbaki, 24ème année (1971/1972), Exp. No. 409, pp. 167–200. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 317, Springer, Berlin, 1973.

And also:

Katz, Nicholas M.(1-PRIN); Tate, John(1-TX)
Bernard Dwork (1923–1998). 
Notices Amer. Math. Soc. 46 (1999), no. 3, 338–343. 
0

Answer (score 3):

You could start with the book by Dwork, Gerotto and Sullivan, "An introduction to G-functions", published by Princeton University Press in the collection Annals of math studies. It contains a full account of the rationality of the zeta function, and the beginnings of the study of p-adic differential equations.